# Navbar sections are displayed incorrectly on chrome and safari, while they're okay on firefox or new chrome

Tags: html, css, web

Navbar sections are supposed to be hidden until you hover on them, revealing them, but on a testing program, [old chrome displays them weird, also on safari](https://pasteboard.co/NuCEfMdvnxNs.png)

the link to the website:https://mat.eckari.sk/
Link to files (index.html is main file and domov.css is style to them): https://github.com/sudolake/SOC

I'm sure it's something stupid in the css but I have no idea and I'm presenting it in 2 hours, I wouldn't be asking if I wasn't. I really need any help you can give, it seems like the sections on the navbar are not responding to font changes in the weird version

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878) - no. And don't just send us to external repositories either. A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into the question.

Comment: Please take a look at this [article](https://www.thoughtco.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867)